# What CSS can I use that will scale the canvas to fill its container without changing its aspect ratio?

Tags: css, html, canvas

I have a canvas with a specific size (lets, say 300x150). What CSS can I use that will scale the canvas to fill its container without changing its aspect ratio and center it both horizontally and vertically for any extra space that's left after scaling.

I tried this

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

canvas {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

<div id="container">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

That works for everything except vertical centering. I tried changing `#container` to a `table-cell` with `vertical-align: middle` with an outer container with `display:table`. That got vertical centering but it no longer scaled horizontally. I tried changing `#container` to flex box but then it started scaling the canvas vertically wrong.

Any other ideas?

---

So this kind of works.

```
canvas {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Unfortunately the canvas is never stretched, only shrunk

Comment: Not sure but [this article](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) might be relevant to your situation?

Comment: I tried every technique in that article. None of them work. I think the issue is setting the canvas to `width: auto; height: auto` breaks all of those techniques

Answer (score 0):

This might be off topic given your question's tags, but here's a way with javascript.

Note: You can convert this example's jquery to pure javascript if desired--there's no critical use for the jquery.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;
var $canvas = $('#canvas');
var $container = $('#container');
var $containerWidth = $('#containerWidth');
var $containerHeight = $('#containerHeight');
$containerWidth.val($container.css('width'));
$containerHeight.val($container.css('height'));
scale();

$('#containerWidth,#containerHeight').change(function() {
  scale();
});

function scale() {
  var containerW = $containerWidth.val();
  var containerH = $containerHeight.val();
  var scale = scalePreserveAspectRatio(cw, ch, containerW, containerH)
  $container.css('width', containerW);
  $container.css('height', containerH);
  $canvas.css('width', cw * scale);
  $canvas.css('height', ch * scale);
  if (Math.abs(containerW - cw * scale) < 2) {
    $canvas.css('top', parseInt((containerH - ch * scale) / 2));
    $canvas.css('left', 0);
  } else {
    $canvas.css('top', 0);
    $canvas.css('left', parseInt((containerW - cw * scale) / 2));
  }

}

function scalePreserveAspectRatio(canvasW, canvasH, maxW, maxH) {
  return (Math.min((maxW / canvasW), (maxH / canvasH)));
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ivory;
}
#container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Container=blue, Canvas=red</h4>
Width:&nbsp
<input type=range id=containerWidth min=100 max=500 value=350>
<br>Height:&nbsp
<input type=range id=containerHeight min=100 max=300 value=200>
<div id=container>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=150></canvas>
</div>
```